# Pass result from bash back to PHP using exec

Tags: php, bash

I to want call a bash function with 'exec'/'bash_exec' in PHP, and then get the result back into PHP code. Something like:

```
<?php
..
..

//bash funct. definitions
$my_bash_function_path='/usr/bin/ls';
$my_bash_param1='x1';
$my_bash_param2='dsfx1';

//clling bash function
exec( $my_bash_function_path." ".$my_bash_param1." ".$my_bash_param2 );

//doing something with a result of bash function
echo ("some_output_of_bash_function");
..
..
?>
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Why did you don't accept one answer?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the signature of the function:

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

If you use the second parameter of the `exec` function, you'll get the output. More details here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

you could also run the bash command like this:

```
$command=$my_bash_function_path." ".$my_bash_param1." ".$my_bash_param2;
$results=`$command`;
echo $results;
```

backticks makes php execute the string inside and return the result